# VS2019 class constructor with different signatures requires all signatures types be included as references by calling program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, constructor

This has been reported via VS2019 feedback mechanism, but I need a solution quicker. Code snippets are below. Apologies for not knowing how to format this better.

Library class has three constructors, the calling test program in same solution which is .NET V4, is required to have a reference to System.Web when it is not needed. When System.Web is referenced and imported, problem occurs that VS2019 V16.6 thinks Newtonsoft.Json V9.0.1 is being referenced. This is on the critical path for a WS2008R2 (VS2010) to WS2019 (VS2019) migration. Problem not seen on WS2012 or WS2016, both with VS2010.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning The primary reference “C:\Users\grollman\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\WriteToQB\WriteToQB\bin\Debug\WriteToQB.dll” could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly “Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed” which was built against the “.NETFramework,Version=v4.5” framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework “.NETFramework,Version=v4.0”.   TestWriteToQB   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 2081

Library class

```
Public Sub New()
m_Page = Nothing
dicWinFormsCache = New Dictionary(Of String, String)(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
InitCRCTable()
End Sub

Public Sub New(objPage As System.Web.UI.Page)
    m_Page = objPage
    InitCRCTable()
End Sub

Public Sub New(dicIn As Dictionary(Of String, String))
    dicWinFormsCache = dicIn
    InitCRCTable()
End Sub
```

calling test program error statement:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30652 Reference required to assembly ‘System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a’ containing the type ‘Page’. Add one to your project. WriteToQB   C:\Users\grollman\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\WriteToQB\WriteToQB\clsWriteToQB.vb 25  Active

calling test program

```
Dim m_objclsDataFunctions As clsDataFunctions.clsDataFunctions
Public dicSettings As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Private ReadOnly Property objclsDataFunctions As clsDataFunctions.clsDataFunctions
    Get
        If IsNothing(m_objclsDataFunctions) Then
            'Dim applicationCache As System.Web.Caching.Cache = System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache
            m_objclsDataFunctions = New clsDataFunctions.clsDataFunctions(dicSettings)
        End If
        Return m_objclsDataFunctions
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: You say a reference to System.Web is not needed, but your first code snippet shows `Public Sub New(objPage as System.Web.UI.Page)`.  Documentation shows that the System.Web.UI.Page class is indeed inside the System.Web library.  Did you intend for the Page class to come from the System.Web.UI namespace?

Comment: That is the library class which is installed in the GAC. It has three different constructors and is used both by web applications and windows forms applications (actually windows services). Using VS2010 and VS2012, if you did not use the constructor that had a web page argument, a system.web reference was not needed.

Comment: FWIW, part of this issue has something to do with having enabled AutoGenerateBindingRedirects per an earlier log that said:
 Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" ...
Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2081,5): warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true 
The redirects were wrong with the redirected to being the highest version known to NuGet (V12), not the version that was installed in the project (v8).